# unable to make this script work

Tags: vba

i am trying to find all bold and then change their formatting so i am trying to do it with two loops one for find bold words and then other for changing formatting. can someone please tell me how to do it/ any help is much appreciated.
'thank you

```
Sub SearchBoldText()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisDocument.Range(0, 0)
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Format = True
        .Font.Bold = True


        While .Execute
            rng.Select
            rng.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Wend

        Do Until rng = 0
                With Selection.Font
                    .Name = "Times New Roman"
                    .Size = 20
                    .Bold = True
                    .Color = RGB(200, 200, 0)
                End With
                Selection.Find.Execute
            Loop
        End With
    End With
    Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of 2 loops for this matter. Let's say your range is A1 to F40, do as follow. Note that i didn't change the formatting but I've made the cell's background red. You could adjust to your needs.

**For EXCEL :**

```
Sub SelectBold()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range

    Set WorkRng = Range("A1:F40")

    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Rng.Font.Bold Then
            Rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**For WORD:**

```
Sub findBold()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Size = 20
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.ColorIndex = wdYellow
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, THank you very much for replyingg but I want to make it work it word, What changes need to be done to make it work with word document. Regards

Comment: @administr4tor look at the updated answer.Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for word script update but i tried and its not working completely. its skipping first line Bold words and its only highlighting one bold word while there are more bold words right next to first one. please check screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/xPupA56.jpg and how do i put this code to change all bold to any font and size i want                                                                     .  .Name = "Times New Roman"
                    .Size = 20
                    .Bold = True
                    .Color = RGB(200, 200, 0)

Comment: @administr4tor see my updated code. This should work.